# Angular 2: dynamic routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have large data tree on the server and I need to make it possible to type urls like "myapp.com/tree/city-123/street-11/apt-1"
In this case static route declaraction is not an option because data tree definded in database. I also don't want to build corresponding route tree dynamically because it's too big, I need just one branch at a time. 
What I need is just to analyze URL and show corresponding component. Please point me direction to go, if any.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Each part of URL should be of random type and their order should be random too:

- myapp.com/city/home/person
- myapp.com/city/city/city/home/account
- myapp.com/person/street/city
- etc.

Comment: Have you read this? : https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann yes but it's about static routing confuguration only. Did I miss something?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Are all of your routes `myapp.com/tree/<some city>/<some street>/<some apt>`? If so, then those can just be route parameters.

Comment: @DeborahK no, each part of path can be of any type. It can be myapp.com/tree/<city>/<city>/<city> for example.

Comment: Does it have to use the slash syntax? If not, you could instead consider optional or query parameters. They allow you to pass and read parameters but don't require them to be pre-defined in a route configuration.

Comment: @DeborahK sorry, no, I need good looking URLs. I've found the solution, this is done by using "matcher" attribute in route. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This is done by presenting route with custom [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher)

Matcher is just a function which analyzes path and desides if route is suitable for this path. So I made matchers which checking not the whole URL:

`mysite.com/city-17/street-333/building-22`

but just last part of it:

`building-22`